# Is it possible to use a data element to set the reporting suite within Adobe DTM?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have an Adobe Activation (DTM) container that I would like to dynamically set the reporting suite value using data elements, such as "%reportingSuiteProd% and %reportinSuiteStage%.

When I try to use these values within the Adobe Analytics tool, they are passed as strings instead of using the data element functionality. Is it possible to use data elements here? If not, what is the cleanest way to set a dynamic reporting suite value within DTM?

Example: 
http://trackingserver.com/b/ss/%reportingSuiteProd%/1/JS-1.6.1-D6I2/s53779788912776.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reasons unclear to anybody, Adobe does not allow data element references to be used for the report suite fields. If you want to use a data element to populate the report suite, you will need to change the settings in **Library Management**.

Set the **Code Configuration** to "Custom" and then check the checkbox for "Set report suites using custom code below".

Then, within the "**Code Hosted** > `In DTM`" Editor (or within the **Customize Page Code** Editor) you can do this:

```
if (_satellite.settings.isStaging)
  s.account=_satellite.getVar('reportingSuiteStage');
else
  s.account=_satellite.getVar('reportingSuiteProd');
```

The major downside to this is if your previous setup was to have the Adobe Analytics library **Managed by Adobe**, well, that is no longer an option, and you will need to ensure the library is kept up to date yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. I was able to set the reporting suite dynamically in the "custom code" section, but didn't realize I needed to also manually host the library. I just learned the hard way that if you do not do this, your custom reporting suite logic will not fire within your event-based rules. What a pain, hopefully this is resolved soon.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided is correct, but i recomend instead of put the report of the suit directly on the data element, save the data first and then use it.

In my personal experience, do it in that way only solve some issues related with the pageview and no with the interactions, if you use local var you provide a robust solution:

**The code is**

```
var reportSuite;
if (_satellite.settings.isStaging)
  reportSuite=_satellite.getVar('reportingSuiteStage');
else
  reportSuite=_satellite.getVar('reportingSuiteProd');

s.account = reportSuite
```

Comment: umm, I'm sorry, but I disagree. Putting it in a local variable `reportSuite` in no way adds to or solves for any of this. I have a sneaking suspicion if this somehow "solved" something for you, it was because you were using that `reportSuite` namespace somewhere else and there was a namespace and/or scope conflict

Comment: @CrayonViolent 
That is the solution from the Adobe Support, related from almost the same issue,  i fixed the problem as the same way as you, but it not solve the interaction problem.

Comment: The only reason Adobe Support would have given you that solution was for the exact reason I mentioned: namespace conflict somewhere else. Again, unless you were using `reportSuite` somewhere else and it was causing a namespace conflict, there is NO functional difference between what you did vs. what I did.  This isn't even about Adobe syntax. It's javascript 101.